# Why does bindingSource = newBindingSource not refresh data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have this in my form's designer code:

```
this.referenceNumberTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.clientDetailBindingSource, "ClientDetails.ReferenceNumber", true));
```

In a method in the form just before it gets displayed I say

```
this.clientDetailBindingSource = passedInBindingSource;
```

The controls that are databound to `this.clientDetailBindingSource` do not show any data.

I have also tried doing ResetBindings() but nothing happened.

Comment: I know, it sounds stupid, but: does the new binding source actually contain the expected data when you inspect it in a debug session?  Or do you use statically bound property descriptors?

Comment: It does contain data 2 items in a list of List<MyClass>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the textbox's DataBindings contains a Binding object that references the original binding source; reassigning the form's data member does not alter the Binding object already created

in other words, the textbox's binding is still bound to the old binding source

unless you're performing this assignment *before* the call to InitializeComponent in the form's constructor...?

Comment: I am changing the bindingsource that the control is bound to though so the control should reflect the changes

Comment: @[Jon]: no, you're not; you just think you are! ;-) InitializeComponent creates the Binding objects which tie the controls to the whatever the bindinsource object is at that instant. Changing the bindingsource object on the form later does not magically alter the Binding objects already created.

Comment: Can I change the bindingsource in the existing binding object without doing a remove/add?

Comment: @[Jon]: unfortunately not - DataSource is a read-only property in the Binding class.